# Prove that $a=2,b=2,c=2$ for a system of three equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, systems-of-equations

Let us consider a   system equations :
\begin{gather}  
a^3+b=3a+4\tag{i}\\
2b^3+c=6b+6 \tag{ii}\\
3c^3+a=9c+8\tag{iii}
\end{gather}

I have tried with the following steps :
$6\times(i)+3\times(ii)+2\times$(iii) gives :
$6(a^3+b^3+c^3)+6b+3c+2a=18(a+b+c)+58$. But  I don't know how to solve in this way. By inspection method I have seen $a=b=c=2$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solve the equations of three variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573459/solve-the-equations-of-three-variables)

Comment: Unfortunately the same question uploaded twice. I have deleted the other duplicate post. This is my actual problem. Any positive suggestion is acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: There is no *general* way but using numerical approximations such as [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) you may be able to prove a convergence of some sort. However I am not sure if this is a rigorous enough proof.

Answer (score 3):

Write the equations as

\begin{align*}
(a-2)(a+1)^2 = 2-b\\
2(b-2)(b+1)^2 = 2-c\\
3(c-2)(c+1)^2 = 2-a
\end{align*}
Note that $(a,b,c) = (2,2,2)$ is a valid solution.

$a>2 \Rightarrow b<2\Rightarrow c>2 \Rightarrow a<2. $ A similar logic precludes $a<2$. This forces $a=b=c=2$ which is the unique solution

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but you can rewrite the system as.

$$ b=-a^3+3a+4\\
c=-2b^3 + 6b+6 \\
a=-3c^3+9c+8$$

Now, you can substitute the first into the second and that result into the third.

This will show one of the roots, $a = 2$ immediately and another useless one.

You can then sub back in the other two and derive the other two roots.